# Tableau Web Data Connector to Google Sheets

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to build a connection between Tableau Public and Google Sheets.

Here is the repository:

https://github.com/AschHarwood/AschHarwood.github.io

and here is the page where you would enter the link to the google sheet:

https://aschharwood.github.io/GoogleSheetsConnector.html

However, nothing happens when I click connect. I have a feeling that I am missing a necessary file.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau 10 has a native connector to Google Sheets, but if you cannot wait that long then just get free [Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/).